# How to store data in two separate mongo db server

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-4.0

I have application which uses mongo db currently I have one instances of mongo db server in my first data center in my another data center I have second  mongo db instances what I want to archive is application to store data in both data centers mongo db instances at same time I know about replica set which won't be useful as I want capabilitie of read and right on both data center

Answer (score 0):

I would say that solution is... [Changestreams!](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/changeStreams/)

With that, you can replicate changes from DC1 to DC2.